# Mongoose httpserver - WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth", realm="mydomain.com" - 401 Unauthorised Error

Tags: authentication, jasmine, http-status-code-401, httpserver, mongoose-web-server

I am trying have a http local host using mongoose-5.3 (a C Code).
As I run the exe over a specific port and I try to make a call from client I get this error

*HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth", realm="mydomain.com"*

I am using a jasmine test framework for doing the above.

could anyone please help me regarding this ?

Below is the log I print out of the mongoose connection structure.

```
**Request method GET
URI /tts 
HTTP Version 1.1
Query String (null) 
HTTP Version 1.1
Header name Upgrade 
Header value websocket
Header value (null)
local_ip 0.0.0.0
remote_ip 127.0.0.1
remote_port 37051
local_por 8887**
```

Eager for the solutions.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem using Mongoose, but after change my server to use the Civetweb, the problem was fixed.

[Civetweb](https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb) has same Mongoose features, but it is distributed under MIT license, and you can download that [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/civetweb/).